# ActiveRecord find position (index) of record within relation based off value of attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a collection ActiveRecord `User` objects. `User` has an attribute, `engagement`, which is a float. Assuming `users = User.all.order(engagement: :desc)` returns 1000 records and `current_user` is a `User` object within `users`, I would like to know the position or index `current_user` within `users` without querying the database again or using an enumerator method such as `each_with_index`, which is slow. Is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

collect the `ids` and find the index of the `current_user.id`

```
index = User.all.order(engagement: :desc).map(&:id).index(current_user.id)
```

you can just pluck the id to avoid map

```
index = User.order(engagement: :desc).pluck(:id).index(current_user.id)
```

Comment: This is great! Cut down the response time by about 30% in my tests. Thanks

Comment: @usha - thank you for the answer: do you know how to get the index if the records are larger than 1000 records: this approach might be problematic for large sets due to memory issues?

Comment: @BenKoshy Is there a better alternative that you might propose, please?

Comment: This was a long time ago. But now you can use a window function with row_number - and then get the current user you want, or perhaps you can  use what @montrealmike has suggested - it's feels hacky, but it does the job. Don't forget to order the results.

Answer (score 1):

@BKSpurgeon You can do this entirely in the DB using something like

```
User.where("engagement < ?", current_user.engagement).count + 1
```

Comment: `User.where("engagement <= ?", current_user.engagement).count` to avoid the `+ 1` at the end

Comment: Nicely done ---> BUT don't forget: they must be ordered: and then you will get the "index" within the relation object.